# Pytest not able to register command line arguments

Tags: python, pytest

This is my folder structure:

```
service
|
|--foolib
     |
     |--src
         |
         |--main
            |
            |--python3
                |
                |--foolib
                    |
                    |--conftest.py
```

and I run pytest from the root directory (service)

Here are the contents of conftest.py:

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--dc", action="store", dest="dc")

def pytest_configure(config):
    DC = config.getoption("dc")
    #do something with DC
```

When I run pytest from the root directory:

```
==================================================================================================================== test session starts =====================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/test/service
plugins: testrail-2.5.3
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

=========================================================================================================================== ERRORS ===========================================================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test session ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:1463: in getoption
    val = getattr(self.option, name)
E   AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'dc'
....

E   ValueError: no option named 'dc'
================================================================================================================== short test summary info ===================================================================================================================
ERROR  - ValueError: no option named 'dc'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
====================================================================================================================== 1 error in 0.15s ======================================================================================================================
```

How can I resolve this? Am I missing something in the conftest?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  What version of pytest/python are you using?  what is `Settings`? replacing `settings` with a dict and having a single test which simply checks the val is in that dict it runs for me as expected

Comment: Settings.DC is just a static variable in Settings class somewhere. Please ignore it. Consider it to be DC=config.getoption("dc"). Even that os not working from me. Where you running pytest from? @2e0byo

Comment: @RhatBhardwaj I think the reason I couldn't reproduce was having `conftest.py` in the root; I didn't trouble to make a bunch of empty directories.  I.e. I think the answer below is correct

Comment: Actually in the real project they are not empty directories...they do have stuff. And this is the required directory structure defined by company. @2e0byo

Comment: oh sure!  I realise that---I just meant that I skipped them *since in my case they'd be empty*.   But it seems you need either to put the conftest in the root, or implement as a plugin.  Note that another option would just be to cd to the dir before running; depending on your test setup that might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

[`pytest_addoption` should only be used either in a plugin or in the `conftest.py` at the root level.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html?highlight=pytest_addoption#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption)

Comment: nice catch; hadn't noticed this wasn't the root